# Load dynamic sequence from Registry - WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I wanted to load a sequence dynmically in the API. If I create sequence is the same ESB Solution project and load, it was successfuly referred the sequence:

```
<property description="supplierSeq" expression="json-eval($.sequence)" name="supplierSeq" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<sequence description="" key="{get-property('supplierSeq')}"/>
```

But if I tried to create the sequence in the registry resource project as mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Working+with+Sequences+via+WSO2+ESB+Tooling#WorkingwithSequencesviaWSO2ESBTooling-DynamicSeq), I could not load it.

```
<property description="supplierSeq" expression="json-eval($.sequence)" name="supplierSeq" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<sequence description="" key="{concat('gov:sequence/', get-property('supplierSeq'))}"/>
```

Please advise.

Comment: Do you get any error?Is the sequence available in governance registry ?

Comment: Yea, I get error that the sequence is not available. But I the sequence is in the registry. Even when I tried to load the sequence with static property, I’m getting the same error.

Comment: Can you provide the error logs and can you let me know what is the media type you have chosen while saving the sequence in registry

Comment: Along with that can you provide the output of $.sequence

Answer (score 1):

I have make the registry path within script mediator and added as a property:

```
payload.sequence = "gov:sequence/" + supplier + "_availability.xml";
```

and then referred for the sequence:

```
<sequence description="" key="{get-property('supplierSeq')}"/>
```

This worked